# get google authentication token using username and password

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, google-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I have been looking for an open google api to get google authentication token by using a user's google username and password. I have came across `google-auth` node package. And according to it, I first need to log in to create a project in google developer console and then use the key to access the information.

But I want to know whether there is any open api where I can directly pass the username and password, without creating any project in google developer console. And get the authentication token as part of response.

This is my first project using google apis, so if it sounds naive please let me know the right way of authenticating a google account user using a node project.

Sorry, I can't provide any code, as I am stuck at understanding the initial part itself, about how to authenticate different users.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use google or any social login, without first creating a project and using it's api key. 
That is just how oAuth is designed.